# Laravel - How to make a function that runs the same time every day?

Tags: laravel

I'm doing a function in laravel, where my user registers a template message:

```
public function createTemplate(Request $request)
{
    if(!($error = $this->isNotValidate($request))){
        //Log::error(print_r("validado", true));

        $message = Message::create($request->toArray());

        //job that runs every day calling my sendMessag

        $response = ['message' => $message];
        return response($response, 200);
    }
    return response($error, 422);
}
```

I want that after registering this mangem, trigger a service that will run every day at the same time, then within this function I will implement my message trigger logic:

```
public function sendMessage()
{
    $messages = Message::where('type', 'like', 'template')->get();
    foreach ($messages as $message){
        if(/*logic if send message or not*/){
            $recive_ids = //get my recive_ids

            $users = User::where('user_group', $recive_ids)->get();

            Notification::send($users, new MessageNotification($message));
        }
        
    }     
}
```

How do I create this job that runs every day calling my sendMessage function?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Laravel Schedule Feature to run your function or any command.

First, you have to find a suitable method for your need.

After that, you have to update the schedule function which is available in `app/Console/Kernel.php`

```
->dailyAt('13:00');
```

As per your requirement, you need a scheduling method dailyAt().

Second, add the `schedule:run` command in crontab to run every minute

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

You should refer to this document for more information[Schedule Document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling)